How to Remove Duplicate Elements in an XML File Using Regex in VS Code?
I have an XML file with several elements, and each child of item appears twice. The file looks something like this:
<item>
    <array name="time_entries">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>10</item>
    </array>
    <array name="time_entries">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>10</item>
    </array>
    <array name="game_level">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </array>
    <array name="game_level">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </array>
</item>


I want to remove the duplicate elements with attribute name from the root.
I tried VS Code find and replace using Regex options. I entered (<item name=".*">#...</item>)(\s*\2) in the find field and $1 in the replace field.

XML does not work well with regex. It would seem to be better to parse the XML, then remove the duplicated elements from the parsed result.

remove all leading spaces, then remove all newlines, place newlines after </array> and before first <array, then sort all the lines with <array and filter with uniq command

That works thanks. I removed all newline characters and leading spaces, then sort all the lines with <array and filter with uniq command

I used regular text editor. VS Code was making extra changes.

Are there always just one duplicate and it is right after the first one?  If so, you can do this via a regex.  If so, try (^\s*<array name="([^"]+)"[\s\S]*?<\/array>)\n\1 and replace with $1.  See https://regex101.com/r/H7LJcJ/1.

It is much better to use XSLT for such task. Regex is unusable for XML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

There are people who love their Swiss Army knife so much, they would use it in place of a hedge trimmer.

regex101.com/r/H7LJcJ/1 is useful even for very large files where text editors hang

And https://regex101.com/r/H7LJcJ/2 if more than one duplicate to be removed.

@MichaelKay Which is the Swiss Army knife in this case?

@Mark regular expressions

Such tasks are made for XSLT.
Input XML
<item>
    <array name="time_entries">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>10</item>
    </array>
    <array name="time_entries">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>10</item>
    </array>
    <array name="game_level">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </array>
    <array name="game_level">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </array>
</item>

XSLT 1.0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="uniqueArray" match="array" use="@name"/>

    <xsl:template match="/item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="array[count(. | key('uniqueArray',@name)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<item>
  <array name="time_entries">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>10</item>
  </array>
  <array name="game_level">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
  </array>
</item>

c#
void Main()
{
   const string SOURCEXMLFILE = @"e:\Temp\input.xml";
   const string XSLTFILE = @"e:\Temp\process.xslt";
   const string OUTPUTXMLFILE = @"e:\temp\output.xml";

   try
   {
      XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();

      using (XmlReader src = XmlReader.Create(SOURCEXMLFILE))
      {
         XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
         xslt.Load(XSLTFILE, new XsltSettings(true, true), new XmlUrlResolver());

         XmlWriterSettings settings = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone();
         settings.IndentChars = "\t";
         // to remove BOM
         settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

         using (XmlWriter result = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUTXMLFILE, settings))
         {
            xslt.Transform(src, xslArg, result, new XmlUrlResolver());
            result.Close();
         }
      }
      Console.WriteLine("File '{0}' has been generated.", OUTPUTXMLFILE);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}


OMG .... You write a complete c# code for it ... Awesome
